# BIOS manipulation

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I have the [Gigabyte GA-M57SLI-S4](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2539#sp) motherboard. But it does not have "quick boot" feature, I.e it does not just show the vendor logo and start up the OS; it has to go through all the steps like most old motherboards. also I have the latest BIOS update. so my question is, *if this "quick boot" feature is not supported by the vendor, are my hands tied?*

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't have that option. Maybe it's called something else? Maybe you're just looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: i'm certain that there is no such option.

Comment: So-called “quick-boot” features don’t really speed things up by any significantly discernible amount. The board still has to do its startup routines (POST, resetting and initializing devices, etc.) The only difference is that it saves a fraction of a second by not displaying the POST on screen, but then displaying a big bitmap for the logo takes about the same amount of time. In any case, the OS does not boot until after the board has initialized. (Your board doesn’t use EFI.) Is the board scanning the entire memory? If so, then there likely is an option, as RP said, but with some other label.

Comment: @Synetech inc is right.  "Quick Boot" is mostly an illusion, and the logo can actually hide useful information.  You're barking up the wrong tree, IMO (unless you do have an extended memory test enabled).

Answer (score 0):

If your current BIOS truly does not support Quick Boot you can look for [alternative BIOS options](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2539#bios) and find one that:

1. Can be flashed to your BIOS chip
2. Offers a Quick-Boot option
3. Is compatible with your motherboard

While flashing a BIOS chip has gotten a lot easier, depending on the method you use you could end up with a corrupt BIOS and few (if any) ways to recover. So if you're not familiar with BIOS flashing then either find someone who is or be very certain you know what you're doing after researching BIOS flashing.

Comment: i actually downgraded my bios version in the hope of seeing a quick boot option. there wasnt one. most probably older versions wont have it. i guess i am stuck with no "quick boot".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just downloaded and checked the BIOS configuration section of the [manual](http://download.gigabyte.ru/manual/motherboard_manual_ga-m57sli-s4_2.0_e.pdf) for your board. There is an option called `Full Screen LOGO Show` in the *Advanved BIOS Features* section:

> **Full Screen LOGO Show**
>
> - Enabled Show full screen logo at system startup. (Default value)
> - Disabled Disable this function. If you wish to see BIOS POST screen, set
>     this item to "Disabled"

What exactly is the issue? Is it that it takes too long to scan the memory?

Comment: yes it does. but your comment to my question above actually is the answer. apparently the board has to go thru the routines, so the logo is only illusion.

Comment: Usually when you see the logo, you can press Escape to get rid of it and see the POST data and such that it was hiding (in other words, all that stuff happens regardless). I actually tried using the logo on my system and quickly decided to get rid of it and watch the information. When I build my mother her first computer, I may enable the logo on it.